# Using Netbeans, the default Maven JavaFX/FXML generates Java files that are flagged as having errors

Tags: java, maven, javafx, netbeans

**The problem:** Using NetBeans 12.6, OpenJDK 17.0.2, JavaFX 17.0.2 on Windows 10, a project created using “FXML JavaFX Maven Archetype (Gluon)” compiles, builds, and runs without problems, but the source files report “duplicate class” for every class and also complain about missing serialVersionUIDs.

If I introduce other errors, they aren’t flagged in the source (the compiler catches them, though). For example, I removed a required throws clause and no error marker appeared.

If I accept the suggestion to suppress the serialVersionUID warning, the “@SuppressWarnings("serial")” message added is itself flagged as an error (“annotation type not applicable to this kind of declaration”). If I try to rename the class using Refactor / Rename, I get a warning “Cannot refactor this object.”

In short, the source parsing seems screwed up, making a lot of essential Netbeans features unavailable. I have no clue as to how to fix it. Most suggestions I've found are resolved by upgrading Java from 8 to 9 (or something like that). I'm using Java 17, so that's not helpful.

I have a Netbeans Ant JavaFX/FXML project that works fine, so the problem is specific to the Maven project. What I know about Maven would fit in a thimble—I was hoping to start with the simple JavaFX application that Netbeans generates and then try moving my Ant project into a Maven project.

---

I create the project using Java with Maven / FXML JavaFX Maven Archetype (Gluon). This asked me to enable JavaFX for Windows and the nb-javac plugin:

[Choose Project dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKhXR.png)

[Enable some additional functionality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVrxZ.png)

After restarting the IDE, I then chose my project. I changed the JavaFX version to 17.0.2 and the javafx-maven-plugin-version to 0.0.8. Here’s the project definition:

[The project definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UR1lA.png)

This image shows the problem. There are error flags for every class. I've hovered over one to display the duplicate class error message (there are no duplicates files).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hcnre.png)

Here’s the module-info.java file:

```
module org.freixas.gamma {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;

    opens org.freixas.gamma to javafx.fxml;
}
```

Here’s the POM file. I added some extra JavaFX dependencies (removing them doesn't change anything):

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.freixas</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.freixas.gamma</artifactId>
    <version>alpha</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-media</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-swing</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.8</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.freixas.gamma.App</mainClass>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running -->
                        <!-- Usage: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Configuration for manual attach debugging -->
                        <!-- Usage: mvn clean javafx:run@debug -->
                        <id>debug</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <options>
                                <option>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=localhost:8000</option>
                            </options>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Configuration for automatic IDE debugging -->
                        <id>ide-debug</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <options>
                                <option>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=n,address=${jpda.address}</option>
                            </options>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Configuration for automatic IDE profiling -->
                        <id>ide-profile</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <options>
                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg1}</option>
                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg2}</option>
                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg3}</option>
                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg4}</option>
                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg5}</option>
                            </options>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <name>Gamma</name>
    <description>A Minskowski spacetime diagram generator.</description>
</project>
```

Comment: This is weird because JavaFX classes aren’t serializable, so they don’t need a serialVersionUID.

Comment: Perhaps download idea community edition, run the [new project wizard](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javafx.html), which will create a Maven fxml JavaFX hello world project, then import the project into netbeans.

Comment: It's even weirder since, as some people on the web point out, it's hard  to get a duplicate class in Java. I'll try IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a solution for NetBeans, I haven't used it in years and the only semi-relevant info I can find on the issue is over ten years old and refers to plugins around the serialVersionUID which don't exist anymore.

Comment: I ran IntelliJ, created a Maven JavaFX project, exported it as an Eclipse project, then tried importing into Netbeans—Netbeans didn't find whatever it needs to identify an Eclipse project. I don't plan to pursue that suggestion further.

Comment: You didn’t need to export to eclipse, idea generated a maven project.  I am sure NetBeans can [open the maven project](https://netbeans.apache.org/wiki/MavenBestPractices.asciidoc#_open_existing_project).  Anyway, hope that you resolve your issue.

Comment: Got it. Yes, I just learned that Netbeans uses maven directly; i.e. it uses the POM file in place of a Netscape project file. But I didn't know that yesterday.  I solved my problem by reading up on Maven, moving my Ant project to Maven on my own and re-opening the revised files in Netbeans. My original question remains unanswered, so I won't try to answer it—I just worked around the problem.